# Editing a embed message

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

So I've been working on a bot and i have a embed message and i would to make a command that would edit the previous embed
So I have tried

```
        let msg2 = msg.channel.messages.fetch('mymessageid').then(
      msg2.edit(yellow)
    )
```

and didn't work out so if you can help me with this

Answer (score 0):

You would need to get the embed from the already sent message, edit that embed, then use `Message.edit({ embeds: [newEmbed] })`.